# ASUS PCE-N15 won't work

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, internet, asus

I've been tearing my hair out trying to get a wireless adapter to work, and I've searched various forums for answered and tried lots of commands that I don't really get but didn[t seem to make any difference... it's using the RTL8192ce drive (I believe) and from what I've found it's a very problematic driver. I bought the ASUS wireless adapter because it specifically said compatible with ubuntu linux kernal 2.6 (although I know I'm not running this kernal I foolishly thought it would work with Ubuntu 14.04).

I might be able to take it back but its a long shot. Has anyone had any luck with ASUS PCE-N15 or am I fighting a lost cause? It appears to be recognised as hardware, just no internet connections show up.

I'm a complete beginner so I know that posting various outputs to commands help but am not sure which ones. I have internet access through a friends computer but my desktop has no internet access and therefore I can't directly download things. I'm wondering if there is an old driver that works better etc. as many of the previous forum posts I've seen have suggestions but are unclear on whether the individual who asked actually solved it or not.

Would installing Kernal 4.0 help? I've come across a suggestion that it worked for someone, is there a way I can install it without my PC being connected to the internet, as the instructions I've come across reqiuire an internet connection.

Thanks
Josh

EDIT: output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
    josh@josh:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8178] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:84b6]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

Comment: Please give output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Then `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: done, edited with output

Comment: Not exactly this command. But OK. I updated my answer. Download `rtlwifi-new-dkms`, remove other deb files from home folder and install same way.

Comment: But there may be an error with conflict. Run `sudo apt-get remove rtl8192cu-dkms` first.

Comment: Done - I actually downloaded the rtlwifi-new-dkms from here: https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+build/7523576 as I didn't see your link below but it looks the same version. unistalled first as well

Comment: So? Does it work? If not give output of `rfkill list`

Comment: not working im afraid. have posted output

Comment: Please give full output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: done and output posted above

Comment: Everything looks good, but I have no more ideas.

Comment: OK, thanks very much for your time and help. Hopefully I'll find a solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a driver. Connect to internet by wire or another way and run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

If you can not connect to internet, then download these files:

[dkms](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.1_all.deb), [rtlwifi-new-dkms](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.5~trusty_all.deb), [linux-firmware](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb)

Copy then to your home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

On some systems there may be error messages asking to install additional packages. If this is the case, post output to your question.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. When I try 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi' I get this: 
Cannot add PPA" 'ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi'
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: Are you connected to internet?

Comment: Ah, apologies didn't see the part about connecting to the internet another way. I'm afraid I don't have another method at the moment, can I download the driver on a different PC, burn and install from a CD rom?

Comment: I will update my answer with an offline guide.

Comment: Is your system 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I've edited my above post with the output

Comment: It looks good..

Comment: Yeah, seemed no problem with the install. But no networks are appearing my the connection list.  I'm a bit stuck. Any commands you know of that I could post the output for which might help?

Comment: Add `lsusb` to your question

Comment: it's a PCI wireless adapter, is there an equivalent command?

Comment: found it, will post lspci result

Comment: No. Use another command. I comment your question.